# React-Native to NodeJS Server - Sending Client Stream (video) from React to the NodeJS Sever and then send back to the Client again

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io, webrtc

I have managed to retrieve the Video Stream from my React Native client using mediaDevices, also the React Native Client is connecting to my NodeJS Server. Once connected the server responds to the Client saying that the Client has connected to the NodeJS server. But once connected i want to send a Video Stream that i get from the mediaDevices and send the Video Stream to the NodeJS server and then in return send the Video Stream back from the NodeJS Sever to the React Native client again.

Your probably asking why don't you just stream the Video straight onto the client rather than sending it to the server and back to the client again.

The reason is that i just want to learn how to use socket.io and socket.io-client to send and receive video streams.

Here is some of the code and how im trying to achieve this atm (Sevrer.js):

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
        
        if(!patients[socket]){
            patients[socket.id] = socket;
            patients[socket.id].emit('PatientConnected', 'Success');
            console.log(`a user connected :D ${socket.id}`);
        }else{ 

        }

        patients[socket.id].on('stream', function(data) {
            console.log("stream from client " + data.stream);
            var bufArr = new ArrayBuffer(data.stream);
            var bufView = new Uint8Array(bufArr);
            patients[socket.id].emit("ReturnStream", bufView);
        });

        socket.on('error', function() {
            delete patients[socket.id];
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            delete patients[socket.id];
        });
    });
```

And my Client (App.js):

```
const socket = io.connect("http://192.168.1.107:3000", {reconnect: true});

  console.log("socket: " + socket);
  socket.on("PatientConnected", (msg) => {

      if(msg == 'Success'){
        console.log("socket connected: " + socket.id);
      }


  });
  socket.on("ReturnStream", (stream) => {

    console.log("ReturnStream: " + stream);
    var bufView = new Uint8Array(stream);
      this.setState({ stream : bufView})
  });

const isFront = true;

  const facing = isFront ? 'front' : 'environment';
  mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(sourceInfos => {
    let videoSourceId;
    for (let i = 0; i < sourceInfos.length; i++) {
      const sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
      if(sourceInfo.kind == "videoinput" && sourceInfo.facing == (isFront ? "front" : "back")) {
        videoSourceId = sourceInfo.deviceId;
      }
    }
    mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: {
        mandatory: {
          minWidth: 500, 
          minHeight: 300,
          minFrameRate: 30
        },
        facingMode: (isFront ? "user" : "environment"),
        optional: (videoSourceId ? [{sourceId: videoSourceId}] : [])
      }
    })
    .then(stream => {
      if(socket){
        console.log('stream' + stream);
        socket.emit('stream', {stream: stream});
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // Log error
    });
  });
```

I am getting undefined in bufView from "var bufView = new Uint8Array(stream);", where am i going wrong or what am i missing something?. I am new to socket.io and socket.io-client, are these the libraries that allow the systems to send and receive Video Streams? and how can this be achieved?